# Find a + b + c + bc.

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

My math trainer friend ask my help to look for the shortest possible solution for this problem:

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be *positive integers* such that 
$$\left \{\begin{matrix}a + b + ab = 15 \\ 
b + c + bc = 99 \\
c + a + ca = 399\end{matrix}\right. $$

> Find $a + b + c + bc.$

I tried elimination but it took us for about 3 min to do it. This question was intended for 15 seconds only.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I'd start by adding $1$ to each of the equations.

Comment: @quid that is the best approach

Comment: @Shaun we tried the elimination.

Comment: @quid, could you please show your solution. Thank you.

Comment: To expand on quid's hint, notice that $a+b+ab+1=(a+1)(b+1)$

Comment: If you don't see a trick like the one that quid suggested, then observe that $a$ and $b$ must be fairly small if $a+b+ab=15$. There are only a few possibilities; once you have those, you can find which one is consistent with the other equations.

Comment: The idea of quid's comment is that we can use the factorisation $1+x+y+xy=(1+x)(1+y)$. Also, the second and third right-hand sides practically scream that they want $1$ added to them.

Comment: Some others stepped in already so I guess that's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding $1$ to each equation, we get that 
$$\left \{\begin{matrix}a + b + ab +1 = 16 \\ 
b + c + bc+1 = 100 \\
c + a + ca+1 = 400\end{matrix}\right. $$
Factoring, we get
$$\left \{\begin{matrix}(b+1)(a+1) = 16 \\ 
(b+1)(c+1) = 100 \\
(c+1)(a+1) = 400\end{matrix}\right. $$
Dividing equation 2 from equation 3 and multiplying the result with equation 1, we get that $(a+1)^2=64$, meaning $a+1=8$. Equation one gives us $b+1=2$, and equation three gets us $c+1=50$, getting that
$$a+b+c+bc=7+1+49+49=106$$

Comment: Rather than doing the final addition the long way, you can use the fact that $b+c+bc=99$.

Comment: This should be correct. I did the same method just now and was about to answer when I saw this. Good work!

Comment: You don't need mucb brute force - you get that $b+1\mid\gcd(16,100)=4$, so, since $b$ is positive, $b=1$ or $b=3$.

Comment: Thank you. To improve this part, maybe we can remove the gussing and use equations  2 and 3. DIvide the 3rd equation by the 2nd equation which wil lead us to 4. This will be relate to equation 1 that will give us a+1 should be 8. Thus a is 7. Thank you everyone for helping me see the trick.

Answer (score 3):

$(a+1)(b+1) = 16 $
$(b+1)(c+1) = 100$
$(c+1)(a+1) = 400$
Multiply all $3$ equations to get value of $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) = 800$ then
$c+1 = 50,\quad a+1 = 8,\quad b+1 = 2$ , required is $a+(99) = 106$

Answer (score 0):

Also elimination leads to the result (as the OP wanted), namely we obtain exactly two solutions over any field of characteristic zero:
$$
(a,b,c)=(-9,-3,-51),(7,1,49).
$$
Then $a+b+c+bc=7+1+49=106$, since only the positive solution was asked.